# How to Assert we have AssertionError in python?

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a method:

```
def cargo_add(self, new_cargo):
    assert (new_cargo.weight + self.cargo_weight()) \
        <= self.cargocapacity, "Not enough Space left"
```

And i would like to test its functionallyty with someting like:

```
def _test_cargo_add():
    assert cShip.cargo_add(c1) is AssertionError
```

So i can test the error Handling. But when the first assert is wrong the program stopps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your testing framework does not have helpers for that, or you are not using any, you can do this only using builtins by
using `try .. except .. else` and `isinstance`:

```
>>> def f(): # define a function which AssertionErrors.
...  assert False
... 
>>> f() # as expected, it does
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
AssertionError
>>> try: # wrap it 
...  f()
... except Exception as e: # and assert it really does
...  assert isinstance(e, AssertionError)
... else:
...  raise AssertionError("There was'nt any Exception, but we expected an AssertionError!")
... 
>>>
```

or just catch the AssertionError explicitly:

```
>>> try:
...  f()
... except AssertionError:
...  pass # all good, we got an AssertionError
... except Exception:
...  raise AssertionError("There was an Exception, but it wasn't an AssertionError!")
... else:
...  raise AssertionError("There was'nt any Exception, but we expected an AssertionError!")
...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing using unittest you can use [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

```
with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
  cShip.cargo_add(c1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/index.html) you can use [raises](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions):

```py
with pytest.raises(AssertionError) as exception:
    cShip.cargo_add(c1)
```

Also, should you have a custom exception message, you could check for this with the following sort of assert:

```py
assert (
    str(exception.value)
    == "foo bar"
)
```